# Onclick not working on table cells?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently trying to make a tic tac toe board, but it isn't being affected by JavaScript's innerHTML function. I'm trying to change the h1 inside the first cell, which is empty, to say X when the cell is clicked, but it isn't working. Any help is appreciated.

```js
function click1() {
  document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = "X";
}
```

```css
* {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
table {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="1" onclick="click1"><h1 id="text1"></h1></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `onclick="click1()"`

Answer (score 3):

According to my little knowledge you have to call the whole function on the onclick event in CSS.

It should be like:

```
<td id="1" onclick="click1()"><h1 id="text1"></h1></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not pass a reference to the function, instead pass a call to the function

```
<td id="1" onclick="click1()"><h1 id="text1"></h1></td>
```

this is [how it works](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp)